# BuildMaster integration with Subversion

Tags: svn, buildmaster

When configuring Subversion source control integration in BuildMaster, I enter in the subversion URL, username, password, then clicking the "test connection" button I get this error:

"Unable to connect. svn: E125001: Can't determine the user's config path"

The BuildMaster application pool is running under the "NetworkService" Identity in IIS.

When switching the BuildMaster application pool Identity to be my user the connection to subversion works fine. However I would like to keep the build master application pool running on the NetworkService Identity.

Are the any permissions I need to assign to the NetworkService to enable BuildMaster to connect SVN?

Comment: As a test, can you change the service account to run as yourself and try it again? The Test Connection operation runs as the user hosting the web application, which could be the application pool identity if you're hosted through IIS.

Comment: Hi John, I just tested and it did work with my user as the Identity for the BuildMaster application pool. I have updated the question to reflect this.